# getting X and Y values from an onTouchEvent in android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android airplane shooter game and I need to get the X and Y position each time the player moves his airplane in order to detect collision.

the class below handles the movement of the player's airplane

```
package com.pe44.dukes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class DukesGame extends Activity {
    final DukesEngine gameEngine = new DukesEngine();
    private DukesGameView gameView;
    public static float playerPosX, playerPosY;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new DukesGameView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       gameView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       gameView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //
        playerPosX = event.getX();
        playerPosY = event.getY();
        String SPposX = Float.toString(playerPosX);
        String SPposY = Float.toString(playerPosY);
        Log.i(SPposX, SPposY);
        int height = DukesEngine.display.getHeight() / 4;
        int playableArea = DukesEngine.display.getHeight() - height;
        if (playerPosY > playableArea){
            switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(playerPosX < DukesEngine.display.getWidth() / 2){
                    DukesEngine.playerFlightAction = DukesEngine.player_turn_left;
                }else{
                    DukesEngine.playerFlightAction = DukesEngine.player_turn_right;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                DukesEngine.playerFlightAction = DukesEngine.PLAYER_RELEASE;
                break;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
    public static float getPlayerX(){
        return playerPosX;
    }
    public static float getPlayerY(){
        return playerPosY;
    }

}
```

I need to pass the `playerPosX = event.getX(); and playerPosY = event.getY();` into my renderer class which is going to handle the collision detection.

I have created two get methods

```
public static float getPlayerX(){
    return playerPosX;
}
public static float getPlayerY(){
    return playerPosY;
}
```

the piece of code which i wrote to handle the collision detection in the renderer class

```
private void detectCollisionsOnPlayer(){
    float playerPosX = DukesGame.getPlayerX();
    float playerPosY = DukesGame.getPlayerY();
    String posx = Float.toString(playerPosX);
    String posy = Float.toString(playerPosX);
    Log.d(posx,posy);
    for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++){
        for (int x = 0; x < DukesEngine.total_fighters + DukesEngine.total_jets + DukesEngine.total_warships - 1; x++ ){
            if(enemies[x].posX == playerPosX && enemies[x].posY == playerPosY ){
                Log.d("Game Over", "game over");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the X and Y values do not pass into the two methods I created in the DukesGame class. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: What does `event.getX ()` and the other return?

Comment: it gets the X and Y position of the player airplane each time the screen is touched. its that value which i want to pass on

Comment: What is exactly happening on the screen when you play the game, is the plane just falling down...the touch event isn't working. Or is something else happening. I looked over your code and I can't see why the values aren't getting updated...

Comment: Seeing that you have already declared `public static float playerPosX, playerPosY;` what happen when u try `DukesGames.playerPosX` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an interface instead of setting static values.